# How to share functions which are object properties and avoid duplicate code

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, module, prototypal-inheritance

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var foo = {
    parent: {
        childOne: {
            prop: 1,
            doSomething: function(){
                return this.prop;
            }
        },
        childTwo: {
            prop: 2,
            doSomething: function(){
                return this.prop;
            }
        }
    },
    other: {
        action: function(){
            return foo.parent.childOne.doSomething() +
                foo.parent.childTwo.doSomething();
        }
    }
}

window.alert(foo.other.action());
```

[Live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/YN7G6/4/)

Here the `doSomething()` function is definitely duplicate code and I would like to avoid it, this is something similar to what inheritance solves.

I was thinking if there is any way of doing something along the lines of:

```
parent: {
    doSomething: function(){
        return this.prop;
    }
}
```

But not sure how to actually implement it, is this possible?

Comment: Is there a need for the doSomething function, if you can access the properties directly?

Comment: @KimGysen mainly for organization and some sort of encapsulation. This is also an oversimplified example.

Comment: Hmm ok, just wondering; because the properties are not private, you could simply do: `return foo.parent.childOne.prop + foo.parent.childTwo.prop;` and you are rid of the doSomething repetition...

Answer (score 1):

You would still have to context bind:

```
function something(context){
  return function(){
    return context.prop;
  }
}
```

Now:

```
doSomething: something(this);
```

Now, just call `doSomething()` like you do inside your `foo.other.action` method.

Comment: Yes, that could be a reasonable solution, right now the functions are too short to justify that, if the functions get more complex, it might warrant it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this would allow you to get rid of some duplicated code:

```
var foo = {
    parent: {
        doSomething: function() {
            return this.prop;
        },
        childOne: {
            prop: 1
        },
        childTwo: {
            prop: 2
        }
    },
    other: {
        action: function() {
            var fooPar = foo.parent;
            return fooPar.doSomething.call(fooPar.childOne) +
                   fooPar.doSomething.call(fooPar.childTwo);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YN7G6/5/

Comment: this is an interesting possibility, but it's making me doubt if I have the right approach for this. I am basing my code on this suggestion: http://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/ and it seems to have this disadvantage.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only concerned about duplicate code, you can simply factor out the function. Your `this` already handles binding the proper context.

```
function bar() {
    return this.prop;
}

var foo = {
    parent: {
        childOne: {
            prop: 1,
            doSomething: bar
        },
        childTwo: {
            prop: 2,
            doSomething: bar
        }
    },
    other: {
        action: function() {
            return foo.parent.childOne.doSomething() +
                   foo.parent.childTwo.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to do away with the redundant `doSomething: bar` altogether, you can also use the call method to explicitly bind the context.

```
var foo = {
    parent: {
        childOne: {
            prop: 1 
        },
        childTwo: {
            prop: 2
        }
    },
    other: {
        action: function(){
            return bar.call(foo.parent.childOne) +
                   bar.call(foo.parent.childTwo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure. The magic is all happening in the `this`, which you already have. A good resource for really understand what `this` is all about is here: http://howtonode.org/what-is-this